# Unable to automate sending of email from remote Windows 10 desktop at startup (via Task Scheduler)

Tags: python, windows, outlook, windows-task-scheduler

When Windows 10 remote desktop is rebooted, Task Scheduler (set up for execution when user is logged on or not) saves a file and sends an (empty) email.

The email sending does not work after reboot. It works only when launched manually or triggered by user from Task Scheduler.

I suspect it is related to state into which the machine is rebooted - it never really recovers user session. Could it be related to control against unattended sessions? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2

I thought it can be be worked around by automated logon. Modifying the registries following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon however did not work and it in principle exposes credentials - desktop is used by several users.

Edit: sample python code which works when launched manually from Task Scheduler but not when launched by Task Scheduler at startup.

```
import win32com.client as win32
from datetime import datetime

o = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
Msg.To = "name@mail.com"
Msg.Subject = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
Msg.Send()
```

Comment: If you have a particular code snippet that fails, please include it and provide details. Otherwise it does not look like a programming question.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I added a python code that is invoked with batch file.

Comment: The problem is reduceable to sending email with e.g. powershell script by Task Scheduler at startup. I understand it is a Windows design which prohibits this.

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler is a service, and Outlook cannot be used from a service, even if the user identity is that of an interactive user. Outlook needs a local user with configured Outlook profile to be logged in.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my impression. Is there any way around it?

Comment: You can use something other than OOM, such as EWS or Graph, but using it if Basic auth is disabled, it is a PITA to use it with OAuth (you'd need to register your app with the Exchange tenant, etc.)